# The best practice for convert a complex Jason response to a dto in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to capture a Jason response to a data transfer object in spring boot in a rest API call. here is my response

```
"isvalid":true,
 "message": {
      "normal": {
        "show": true,
        "body": "testing",
        "bodyType": "text"
      },
      "important": {
        "show": true,
        "key": "test",
        "value": "test"
      }   
 },
 "department":"LAB",
 "type":"info",
 "priority":"normal",
```

I want to write the dto class what is the best practice to capture the nested objects in the response. I am currently use static inner classes for message, normal and important. It is working as expected i want to know whether there is a better approach to handle the situation

Here is my dto class,(getters, setters and constructors are not included)

```
public class myDto {

    private boolean isvalid;

    private String department;
    private String type;
    private String priority;

    private Message message;


    public static class Message{
        private Normal normal;
        private Important important;
    }


    public static class Important{
        private boolean show;
        private String key;
        private String value;
    }

    public static class Normal{
        private boolean show;
        private String body;
        private String bodyType;
    }
}
```

Comment: your dto looks pretty good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DTO is perfectly fine regarding the (de-)serialization process of `Jackson`.

Let me just give you some smaller remarks on Java coding conventions:

- `myDto` is a class name and should therefore read `MyDto`
- `isvalid` should be in camel-case because it reflects two words `isValid`
- `type` and `bodyType` could perhaps be a little bit stronger typed. Maybe you could use an `enum` with values such as `TYPE_A`, `TYPE_B` and so on to keep your domain bounded. But this is just a suggestion.

Last but not least: **Pay special attention** that all of your inner classes are always **`static`**, to give `Jackson` a chance to instantiate such classes via their zero-argument constructor. This would not be possible if they were non-static.